# Need same div by its id multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div in html that contain a button and 2 labels i want to create that same div its id (DivBtn) by loop in a separate another div.
it means i want to create div by its ID multiple times in another div

```js
function wardDetlData(data) {

  var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('divBtn');
    newDiv.id = 'divBtn';
    newDiv.className = 'Boxed';
    $("#DivBedOccupancy").append(newDiv);
  }
};
```

I already tried the following:

```
<div class="boxed" id="divBtn" style="margin-top:8px;">
  <div style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:5px;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="background-color:#FF8C00" id="btnAdd" onclick="OnAdd()"><b>GENRAL WARD</b></button>
  </div>
  <br />
  <label><b>REQ CATGEGORY - XXX</b></label><br />
  <label><b>ALLOT CATEGORY - XXX</b></label><br />
  <label><b>TOTAL BED - XXX</b></label><br />
</div>
```

This is my DIV that i want to create by loop multiple times.

Comment: It is generally a bad practise to have multiple elements with same id in the DOM at the same time.

Comment: You seem to have managed to do what you want. What is the problem here?

Comment: What is the use of `data` in your function? maybe show the HTML before and after, so it is clear what change you are trying to make.

Comment: In single html page div tag with id is always unique.

Comment: wow why not using class!

Comment: `id` **must** be unique. Also what is `divBtn` supposed to be in `document.createElement('divBtn')`?

Answer (score 0):

HTML Document having multiple elements with same `ID` is not a valid HTML .
However if you want to use same set of rules in multiple elements you should be using `class`

See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) for more details

And also in your code there is a little typo

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('divBtn')
```

But this creates `<divBtn></divBtn>` instead of `<div></div>` (as supposed) so it should be

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
```

Answer (score 0):

use the backtick  ``` (``) ``` to get dynamic data in newDiv, I hope this will help you.

```
function wardDetlData(data) {
var newDiv ='';
  var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    newDiv+ = `<div id='divBtn' class='boxed'></div>`;
  }
$("#DivBedOccupancy").append(newDiv);

};
```

Comment: thanks but there is syntax error near '=' sign in (newDiv+ = `<div id...`)

Comment: check with other jquery methods to add newDiv to DivBedOccupancy, basically, newDiv contains multiple div like an array, you can check it by console.log(newDiv) 
 after for loop